# Troubles displaying floating points in mips assembly

Tags: mips

I'm having issues displaying my floating points in mips. I've tried two different approaches and both are not working. Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

This is what the first approach

square_root:

```
la   $s0, arrayN       # initalize array parameters

l.s  $f1, 0($s0)       # load coef[a] into $f0
l.s  $f2, 4($s0)       # load coef[b] into $f1
l.s  $f3, 8($s0)       # load coef[c] into $f2
l.s  $f7, four         # load the float 4.0 to $f7

mul.s $f4, $f2, $f2    # square b.$f2 * $f2 = $f4

mul.s $f5, $f1, $f3    # multiply a*c ($f1 * $f3 = $f5)
mul.s $f6, $f7, $f5    # multiply 4*(results of ac)($f7 * $f5 = $f6)

sub.s $f0, $f4, $f6    # b^2-4ac ($f4 - $f6 = $f0)  

li  $v0, 4         # system code call for print string
la  $a0, xEq           # print "x = "
syscall

li     $v0, 2          # system code call for print integer
mov.s  $f12, $f0       # move value to be printed to $f1
syscall                # print the result

jr    $ra                # return to main
```

code displays x = 0.0 it should display x = -8

second approach I took

square_root:

```
la   $s0, arrayN       # initalize array parameters

l.s  $f1, 0($s0)       # load coef[a] into $f0
l.s  $f2, 4($s0)       # load coef[b] into $f1
l.s  $f3, 8($s0)       # load coef[c] into $f2
l.s  $f7, four         # load the float 4.0 to $f7

mul.s $f4, $f2, $f2    # square b.$f2 * $f2 = $f4

mul.s $f5, $f1, $f3    # multiply a*c ($f1 * $f3 = $f5)
mul.s $f6, $f7, $f5    # multiply 4*(results of ac)($f7 * $f5 = $f6)

sub.s $f0, $f4, $f6    # b^2-4ac ($f4 - $f6 = $f0)

swc1  $f0, posX        # output for f(x)

li  $v0, 4         # system code call for print string
la  $a0, xEq           # print "x = "
syscall

li  $v0, 1         # system code call for print string
la  $a0, posX           # print $f0 value
syscall

jr    $ra                # return to main
```

This version displays
x = 268501116 instead of x = -8

Comment: Show us (1) the input values, (2) the formula you're computing; pretty sure that we can't help without that.

Comment: I'm wanting to eventually turn this into a quadratic equation evaluator. The values are input by user ax^2+bx+c I solve the polynomial then I want to try to solve for x      I entered a=1, b=2, c=3

Comment: Right now this function is only trying to compute the b^2-4ac part of the quadratic formula.

Comment: Ok, but what inputs (should) result in -8??

Comment: a=1, b=2, c=3,  so b^2-4ac = x , 2^2-4*1*3=-8. These integers are loaded into the arrayN($s0). a is 0($s0), b is 4($s0), and c is 8($s0).

Comment: Your code looks ok, so maybe the problem is in your data or the caller (you did not shown the rest of the program).